# Can't find the stream provider when using named route navigation

Tags: flutter

I have a Stream Provider (connected to firebase) that is not working. I am guessing that the problem lies in the fact that I am using a named navigator [Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/route',)]. I guess this makes the 'route' widget to not be the son of the widget that calls it. Let me show it better below.

My app structure is as follows:
My **main widget** which handles routing and receives the Stream with user authentication (there is no problem here):

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<User>.value(
      value: AuthService().user,
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Wrapper(),
        routes: {
          '/home': (context) => Wrapper(),
          '/edit_profile': (context) => UserProfile() //This is where I am having trouble.
        }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The **Wrapper** that validates if the user is authenticated and acts accordingly:

```
class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);

    // return either the Home or Authenticate widget
    if (user == null){
      return Authenticate();
    } else {
      return HomeWrapper();
    }

  }
}
```

The **HomeWrapper** which receives the second stream and redirects to the widget I am having trouble with:

```
class HomeWrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeWrapperState createState() => _HomeWrapperState();
}

class _HomeWrapperState extends State<HomeWrapper> {

  String currentBodyName = 'home';
  Widget currentBodyWidget = Home();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    Widget _drawerOptions = Row(
      children: [
        FlatButton(child: someChild, onPressed: () {Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/edit_profile',);},), //This is the actual call to the navigator.
      ],
    );

    return StreamProvider<Map>.value( //This is the problematic Stream!
        value: DatabaseService().userDetail,
        child: Scaffold(
        //Body
        body: currentBodyWidget,

        //I am simplifying this to show the most important parts
        bottomNavigationBar: myBottomNavigationBar(
          buttons: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              icon: someIcon,
              onPressed: () =>  _onItemTapped('home'),
            ),
            FlatButton(
              icon: otherIcon,
              onPressed: () => _onItemTapped('second_screen'),
            ),
          ],)

          //Drawer
          drawer: Drawer(child: _drawerOptions,), //This one has the call to the problematic edit_profile route.
    );
  }

  void _onItemTapped(String newBodyName) {
    if (newBodyName != currentBodyName){
      setState(() {
        currentBodyName = newBodyName;
        switch(newBodyName) {
          case 'home': {
            currentBodyWidget = Home();
          }
          break;

          case 'second_screen': {
            currentBodyWidget = SecondScreen();
          }
          break;

          default: {
            currentBodyWidget = Home();
          }
          break;
        }
      });
    }
  }


}
```

Finally the **edit_profile** route calls the **UserProfile** Widget which looks like this:

```
class UserProfile extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UserProfileState createState() => _UserProfileState();
}

class _UserProfileState extends State<UserProfile> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    //This is where the error occurs!!
    final userDocument = Provider.of<Map>(context) ?? [];
    print(userDocument);

    return Scaffold(body: Container());
  }
}
```

This is the error that it throws:

```
The following ProviderNotFoundError was thrown building UserProfile(dirty, state: _UserProfileState#09125):
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> above this UserProfile Widget
```

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my approach was wrong.

Instead of wrapping the HomeWrapper with the StreamProvider, hoping that it would pass the data to the next route (UserProfile ), what I did was to wrap the UserProfile widget with a StreamProvider, as follows:

(Note: I changed the Map StreamProvider for a UserData StreamProvider.)

```
class UserProfile extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UserProfileState createState() => _UserProfileState();
}

class _UserProfileState extends State<UserProfile> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);

    return StreamBuilder<UserData>(
        stream: DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).userData,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            UserData userData = snapshot.data;

            return Scaffold(
              body: Container(
                   //My Widget here
            );
          } else
            return Loading();
        });
  }
}
```

This series was very helpful: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4cUxeGkcC9j--TKIdkb3ISfRbJeJYQwC